# How does the role assignment work in Postgres Operator?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am using https://postgres-operator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and have deployed:

```
kind: "postgresql"
apiVersion: "acid.zalan.do/v1"

metadata:
  name: "acid-databaker-db"
  namespace: "dev"
  labels:
    team: acid

spec:
  teamId: "acid"
  postgresql:
    version: "12"
  numberOfInstances: 2
  volume:
    size: "2Gi"
  users:
    admin:
      - superuser
      - createdb
    kcadmin: [] 
  databases:
    keycloak: kcadmin
  allowedSourceRanges:
    # IP ranges to access your cluster go here

  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 100Mi
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 500Mi
```

everything is up and running and I can connect to database, but I do not understand this part:

```
  users:
    admin:
      - superuser
      - createdb
    kcadmin: [] 
  databases:
    keycloak: kcadmin
```

According to the [doc](https://postgres-operator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/#prepared-databases-with-roles-and-default-privileges), `admin` is a role - right? 
What about `kcadmin`? Is it an `user` or `role`? If it is an user, what kind of role does the `kcadmin` has?

Comment: admin is a user  ..  and kcadmin too not a role .. superuser and createdb are role for user admin

Comment: @zero_coding Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Yes. It solves my problem. I was also unsure, if I need user admin or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer based on the correct info from the comments and with more explanation and details.

In your use case:

```
  users:
    admin:
      - superuser
      - createdb
    kcadmin: [] 
  databases:
    keycloak: kcadmin
```

we see two users: `admin` and `kcadmin`.

User `admin` has two manifest roles: `superuser` and `createdb`.

User `kcadmin` has no manifest roles.

Manifest roles are defined as a dictionary, with a role name as a key and a list of role options as a value. For a role without any options it is best to supply the empty list `[]`, like with your `kcadmin` user.

The following roles can be used: `superuser`, `inherit`, `login`, `nologin`, `createrole`, `createdb`, `replication` and `bypassrls`.

I hope it helps.